# Change the datatype in the column with data in laravel migration

Tags: laravel, database-migration

This is the migration? i have to change the string data column into integer data column with existing data

```
public function up()
{
       Schema::table('SYS_tenants' ,function (Blueprint $table){
           $table->integer('tena_type')->unsigned()->nullable()->change();
           $table->foreign('tena_type')->references('id')->on('account_types');
       });
}
```

Comment: Which column type do you want to change?

Answer (score 3):

As per laravel Documentation you can create a new migration and do it like this:

```
Schema::table('SYS_tenants', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->integer('tena_type')->unsigned()->nullable()->change();
});
```

> Before modifying a column, be sure to add the `doctrine/dbal` dependency
>   to your `composer.json` file.

```
composer require doctrine/dbal
```

Reference: [Laravel -> Database: Migrations-> Modifying Columns](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/migrations#modifying-columns)

Answer (score 1):

I already use this Laravel Migration

`$table->integer('tena_type')->unsigned()->nullable()->change();`

But it doesn't work because, the data already in the table. In that case it can't change the datatype.I use this DB statement to change the datatype with data.it's working properly.

`DB::statement("alter table SYS_tenants modify tena_type integer not null"):`

Answer (score 0):

## [Migrations#Modifying Columns](https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations#modifying-columns)

Looks like what you have should work:

```
Schema::table('SYS_tenants' ,function (Blueprint $table){
    $table->integer('tena_type')->unsigned()->nullable()->change();
});
```

Depending on your database you may need to cast the values to the new type: (for mysql: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cast/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `change` method on the field which you want to change the type after setting the new field type.

```
public function up() {
    Schema::table('SYS_tenants' ,function (Blueprint $table){

        $table->string('tena_type')->change();   
    });
}
```

I supposed the migration which create the table has already call all requirement you need like `unique`, `nullable` and so on. You can call `change` method, by the way there isn't restriction about any modification you want to perform like add other mysql index on that field.

Do not forget to add **`doctrine/dbal`** in `composer.json` file